# Yii2-how to update multiple record for same user

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This question may be asked several times but I have seen almost all of them but still unable to get an answer.

The flow is simple. A user has been issued `sims`. When sims are issued I am inserting the count of sims against that user in a table called `sim_balance`.

[image]

Now There is a use-case for `SIM Return`. While returning the sim I am updating the above table. As in above image, one can see that total 8 sims have been issued to the same user but with different date time. The code for updating table is below

**Sim Return Create**

```
$model = new SimReturn();
    $result = 0;
    $returned_by = 0;

    try{
        if (isset($_REQUEST['selected_imsi'])) {
            foreach ($_REQUEST['selected_imsi'] as $k => $v) {

                $count = $_REQUEST['selected_imsi'];
                $result = count($count);
                .
                .
                .
                $returned_by = $m->return_by;
                .
                .
                .
                if($m->save())
                {
                    // code...
                }

            }
            // below function call is updating the record
            SimBalance::update_Record($returned_by,$result);
            return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute('/simreturn'));
        }catch (Exception $ex)
         {
           {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
           }
         }
```

**update_Record**

```
    public static function update_Record($user_id,$count){
    $sims = SimBalance::find()->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->one();
    $sims->sims_count = $count;
    $sims->balance_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    return $sims->save();
    }
```

Now, if the `SIMs` returned are from the same `id` then the record is updated perfectly.

But when I try to return the SIM from different `id`, let say I have returned `2` sims from id `1` and `2` sims from id `2` so as they both are for same `user_id` so both the `sims_count` should be updated. But it's just updating the record for id `1`.

**Update 1**

As per suggestion is given, now I am using `update()` by looking into this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#updateAll()-detail).

```
 public static function update_Record($user_id,$count){
     $sims = SimBalance::find()->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->all();
    foreach ($sims as $sim)
    {
        $model = SimBalance::find()->where(['id'=>$sim->id])->one();
        $model->sims_count = $count;
        $model->balance_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        return $model->save();
    }

}
```

But still, it's not working for me, else it places an additional count.

How can I update the record simultaneously for both the `ids`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you see the flaw in your `update_Record()` function?

Comment: @the.salman.a I can use `all()` but then `save()` is not working

Comment: Why don't you use `update` of Yii2? It's pretty easy and it'll update all the records of same user. I can give you the code. Or you can just google.

Comment: @the.salman.a kindly see my `update1`

Comment: Inside `foreach` loop, for each `id` not user_id do `$model = SimBalance::find($sims->id);
$model->sims_count = $cound;
$model->balance_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$model->save();`.

Comment: `find` is not a function

Comment: Did you try `findOne()`? If still doesn't work, do this `$model = SimBalance::find()->where(['id' => $sims->id])->one(); $model->sims_count = $cound; $model->balance_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); $model->save();`. It'll work.

Comment: Do this inside the loop ??

Comment: Yes. Inside the loop.

Comment: ok.. it's saying that `field id not found` and the error is `Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\common\models\SimBalance.php:69`

Comment: Match attributes with your table/model. And update your function, it'll work.

Comment: @the.salman.a the attributes are correct

Comment: `print_r($sims); die;` and see what it gives. On top inside `foreach`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167142/discussion-between-mr-faisal-and-the-salman-a).

Comment: what does the `$_REQUEST['selected_imsi']` has ?

Comment: how do you determine how many sims are returned for sim id `1` and for sim `id` 2

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam `$_REQUEST['selected_imsi']` contains the `imsi` number

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam that what I am asking for

Comment: you have written above that there could be 1 sim returned for `sim_id` 1 and 2 sims for `sim_id` 2 where are you posting this information, are all the selected sims are in the `_REQUEST['selected_imsi']` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes `_REQUEST['selected_imsi']` includes the selected `imsi`

Comment: For example, if sims_count is 5 and I am returning 2 SIMS then the sims_count will be 2 but it should be 5-2 = 3. Moreover, I want to check that for which id is the sim is returning. There would be more than one record against single user.

Comment: i did not quite get the `5-2=3` section, the thing is i want to understand the flow along with the information posted , so what i get is that you are just posting `imsi` numbers that are to be returned and you have to decrement the count in the `sim_balance` for that user to which it belongs, now looking at your `sim_balanace` table, why are you saving 2 records for the same user, why not a single record to have the counter for the sim_balance`, dont you think its odd how are you going to decrement when sim returned which one will be decremented ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167168/discussion-between-mr-faisal-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam multiple records are saved because we have to audit the user details date wise

Comment: then lets say you are getting 2 sims  to be returned how will you determine which sim should be decremented from which record you have no track for that ?

Comment: Yes that's the main issue I am not able to track the `sims`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have just confirmed again, now `they` are saying that keep only single record for same user...

Comment: and thats what. am asking from start you can track it unless there is a single record for the sim balanace

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, can you please give me some tips that how can I update the same record while issuing the `sims` against the same user? Or you want me to add a new question? 

I guess there should be check which will tell that whether this user have record already in `sim_balance` or not?

Comment: let me update my answer

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam still waiting bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to have a single record against the user in the `sim_balance` table as you won't be able to track which row to decrement against the given sims, for instance you are getting 2 sims with id `1` and `2` which belong to the same user now how will you determine that you have decrement-only one of those 2 records or both of them , keep the counter in one single record against the user and decrement it by determining the sims belong to that user

Comment: Yes, it would be a useful and easy way. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MrFaisal when a sim is issued how do you save that record in the table `sim_issueance`? do you have a separate records for each sim issued?

Comment: @MrOmer, yes every sim issued is saved in a separate row in `sim_isseance` table

Comment: you didn't replied at that time so I thought that you would have done it, give me some time and I will reply back @MrFaisal

Comment: Yes, I was gone home. Ok bro @MrOmer

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're returning $model->update(). This means that the foreach will exit in the first loop.

Use instead:

```
public static function update_Record($user_id,$count){
    $sims = SimBalance::find()->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->all();

    foreach ($sims as $model)
    {
        $model->sims_count = $count;
        $model->balance_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $model->update();
    }

return $sims;
}
```

Comment: Not working properly, it updates the `sims_count` with `$count`. For example, if `sims_count` is 5 and I am returning 2 SIMS then the `sims_count` will be `2` but it should be `5-2 = 3`. Moreover, I want to check that for which `id` is the sim is returning. There would be more than `one` record against single user.